# Should I write to invite a professor to be my PhD thesis examiner?

Tags: thesis

My supervisor has already invited formally the professor to be my examiner.
Do I need to invite the professor personally as he may learn more about my work? 
Is there any conflict of interest to do so?

Comment: My uni explicitly said we must not contact examiners ourselves. I'd be slightly surprised if that's universal though. Check your rule-book.

Comment: Vote to close because it is too localised. It depends on the rules and procedures of the institution.

Answer (score 11):

The way in which doctoral examiners are selected will differ between countries, between universities within countries, and within schools. Ask your supervisor for advice on what you should do here and follow their instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your supervisor but I've never heard of PhD students being expected to invite people to examine them.  You're right to worry about conflicts of interest and appearing to try to influence your examiner by contacting them.

Comment: In just depends. In the US model, the examining committee is involved earlier on and it is normal for the student to ask them. For example, although I coordinated with my supervisor, I was the one who approached every person on my general and dissertation examination committees.

Comment: In my experience as an external examiner for dissertations in Canada, Europe, and New Zealand, I have always been invited to be an external examiner by a dean or department chair, with the formal invitation typically proceeded by informal discussions with the advisor.  This is completely different from the situation where I am a member of the dissertation committee for a student at my own institution.  In that situation, it's typical for the student and/or the advisor to ask me if I'm willing to serve.  The committee is then formally appointed by the graduate dean.